# Issue parsing PDF with Apache Nutch - extractor plugin

Tags: pdf, solr, nutch, extractor

I am trying to index web pages AND pdf documents from a website. I am using Nutch 1.9.

I downloade the nutch-custom-search plugin from https://github.com/BayanGroup/nutch-custom-search. The plugin is awsome and indeed let me match selected divs to solr fieds.

The problem I am having is that, my site also contains numerous pdf files. I can see that they are fetched but never parsed. There is no pdf when I query solr. Just web pages. I am trying to use tika to parse .PDFs (I hope that I have the right idea)

If on cygwin, I run parsechecker see below, it seems to parse OK:

```
    $ bin/nutch parsechecker -dumptext -forceAs application/pdf http://www.immunisationscotland.org.uk/uploads/documents/18304-Tuberculosis.pdf
```

I am not too sure what to do next (see below for my config)

**extractor.xml**

```
    <config xmlns="http://bayan.ir" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://bayan.ir http://raw.github.com/BayanGroup/nutch-custom-search/master/zal.extractor/src/main/resources/extractors.xsd" omitNonMatching="true">
<fields>
    <field name="pageTitleChris" />
    <field name="contentChris" />     
</fields>
<documents>
    <document url="^.*\.(?!pdf$)[^.]+$" engine="css">
        <extract-to field="pageTitleChris">
            <text>
                <expr value="head > title" />
            </text> 

        </extract-to>
        <extract-to field="contentChris">
            <text>
                <expr value="#primary-content" />
            </text> 

        </extract-to>

    </document>
</documents>
```

**Inside my parse-plugins.xml i added**

```
    <mimeType name="application/pdf">
       <plugin id="parse-tika" />
    </mimeType>
```

**nutch-site.xml**

```
    <name>plugin.includes</name>
<value>protocol-http|urlfilter-regex|parse-(html|tika|text)|extractor|index-(basic|anchor)|query-(basic|site|url)|indexer-solr|response-(json|xml)|summary-basic|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)</value>
```

```
<property>
  <name>http.content.limit</name>
  <value>65536666</value>
  <description></description>
</property>


<property>
  <name>extractor.file</name>
  <value>extractor.xml</value>
</property>
```

Help would be much appreciated,

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem relates to omitNonMatching="true" in your extractor.xml file.

omitNonMatching="true" means "don't index those pages that don't match in any extracto-to rules of extractor.xml". The default value is false.

Comment: Hi Tahagh, Thanks for replying. I am afraid but setting omitNonMatching to false doesn't solve the issue. :(  In fact, I addded this option after reading an article on Github about someone having a similar issue. https://github.com/BayanGroup/nutch-custom-search/issues/1    Any other idea by any chance?  Thanks Chris

Comment: Have you configured the plugin in mode 1 (as an http parser plugin) or mode 2 (as a standalone parser)? (I'm guessing you are using mode 1 but I want to be sure)

Comment: Another question: if you disable the extractor plugin, will your pdf files be indexed into solr normally?

Comment: By the way, please keep omitNonMatching to false, the issue you were mentioned was asked when the default value of omitNonMatching was true so at that time the solution was to set it to false explicitly.